# Error in the association of two models. (# must exists)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to be able to choose an author when creating a post. I have a Post and Author model. In the author's model, I prescribed `has_many :posts`, and in the Post model `belongs_to :author`. In the form view, created a list of authors `<%= form.collection_select(:author_id, Author.all, :id, :last_name, class:'form-control' ) %>`. In the post controller I prescribed:

```rb
    def post_params
       params.require(:post).permit(:name, :title, :content, :picture, :author_id)
    end
```

schema.rb:

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "author_id"
    t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_posts_on_author_id"
  end
```

But when creating a post, I get an error:
`Author must exist`

logs:

````
Started POST "/posts" for ::1 at 2019-11-18 00:51:40 +0200
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"68iOabMzXQPuvC83f5Oe3kQEl5rFeQLQNCuMjvtRZgfdArdvMs79gKs8MeTNzBcsN0dRjTdRVCFkIrvZqixY1g==", "post"=>{"author_id"=>"2", "name"=>"SomeName", "title"=>"SomeTitle", "content"=>"SomeContent"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Rendering posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[36mAuthor Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors"[0m
  ↳ app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:16
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (Duration: 8.2ms | Allocations: 2071)
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 9.1ms | Allocations: 2157)
Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 30.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 13745)```
````

Comment: I think this code looks good. Can you show more of your controller class?

Comment: Show your models as well. Check if you really have an author with ID 2 in your database. In new rails version belongs_to relations are per default mandatory. `belongs_to :class, optional: true` skips this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Author must exist` error indicates that your new post is failing a validation: the presence of a value for the `author_id` attribute which links a post to an author. This validation comes bundled by default with the `belongs_to` association helper method (and can be disabled as per Simon Franzen's comment above: `belongs_to: model, optional: true`.

Since you're permitting the `author_id` key in `post_params`, the weak link in the chain is either your `post#create` controller action or your `_form.html.erb` view. A couple of suggestions for `post#create`, and `_form.html.erb`, respectively:

```rb
def create
  post = Post.create(post_params)
  redirect_to post
end
```

```rb
<%= form_with model: @post do |form| %>
  ...
  <%= form.label :author %>
  <%= form.collection_select :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name %>
  ...
  <%= form.submit "Create Post" %>
<% end %>
```

We need more of the code for your post controller actions and form view to give a more precise answer.